# Location without GPS

Tags: networking, location, android-wifi, locationmanager, provider

I have a tablet without gps only with wi-fi and I want to get the device location via wi-fi but the network provider gives me always null.
What am I doing wrong? What other options do I have?

```
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) ResourceManager.getActivity().getSystemService(MainActivity.LOCATION_SERVICE);


            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                  // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.

                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
              };
              if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
              }
              //if (locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)!=null)Log.d("xxxx", "xxxx");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two ways.

1. Use the [Google fused location](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) API, I'm pretty sure it will give you a location even if you don't have GPS.
2. get the mac address of the WiFi networks which you see and use an external API to determine the location out of the MAC address.

Comment: today i was trying with Google fused location and  doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ask for the location permissions? can you post your logcat?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  Connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{2cb75660: android.os.BinderProxy@2cb755e0}}